# Ajax Form submit with preventDefault

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a normal HTML form in which it is supposed to  prevent default form submit and post the values by Ajax. It is not working with my setup Please help me where I went wrong. 
See me as Novice in Jquery,javascrip

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery.multiselect.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

       $("select").multiselect({
          selectedList: 4
       });

    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('#contactForm1');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

My Form looks like

```
<form action=index1.php id="contactForm1" method="post">
<p>
    <select name="example-list[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>

    </select>
</p>
<input class="text"  type="submit"  value='GO'>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: AFAIK, `ev.preventDefault();` should come at first. and also you should wrap your code in dom ready event.

Answer (score 23):

Wrap your code in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(function () {
    var frm = $('#contactForm1');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I would move the preventDefault to before the Ajax to not have the form submit normally in case of error in the ajax part

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){

    //call ajax

e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your page refreshing when you submit the form even with `preventDefault()`?

1. On you form, put `#` in the action attribute and remove `method`.
2. Modify your JS code

   `var frm = $('#contactForm1');
   frm.submit(function (ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
           type: frm.attr('method'),
           url: frm.attr('action'),
           data: frm.serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
               alert('ok');
           }
       });
   });`

Put `preventDefault` before your ajax fires. Whats happening on your code is, your form is being executed with the action and method supplied in HTML, therefore your JS cannot catch it.

Answer (score -1):

set the submit button as `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`,

and let's say the submit button has id `submit-button`. you can submit the form in javascript like this:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){ 
 //send ajax
})
```