# Unwanted redirect to POST url after successful ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I do a jQuery ajax POST which successfully delivers the correct data to the server.
After the POST is complete, the browser has redirected to the post url page... which I don't want.  Neither of the alerts occur.  The POST data has arrived at the server just fine.

i.e. after the ajax is performed within a page at `http://myDomain/myPage.html` as shown below, the browser address bar shows `http://myDomain:39991/updateEnabled` and no alerts have happened.

```
   var enabledAjax = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myDomain:39991/updateEnabled',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('#enabledForm').serialize(),
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
    enabledAjax.done(function (msg) {
        alert('done')
    })
    enabledStatus.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert('textStatus');
    })
```

In express, i have `router.post('/updateEnabled', urlEncodedParser, updEnab);`

Within updEnab all I do at the moment is a console.log of req.body and `res.end()`

I've tried a 'success' method within the ajax params but that doesn't work either.
What am I doing wrong that is causing the redirect to the POST url?

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false;` to stop redirection

Comment: How do you trigger your code? From the id `#enabledForm` I think you're most probably clicking on a button inside a form, which fires the form's action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hello when you submit form this is submitting normally so you need to use this.

```
event.preventDefault()
```

this will stop stop normal submitting of form.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352799/ajax-form-submit-with-preventdefaultusing where I figured out where event was coming from.  It stops the unwanted redirects but now the ajax is failing,  I'll post a new question with the updated code that doesn't redirect but also doesn't work :-)

Answer (score 1):

To stop the redirection you can use the return statement like this:

```
 enabledAjax.done(function (msg) {
    return false;
})
```